# add exchange extensions to AD

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365

we have a windows server 2012 with AD on it. we sync that to office 365 but a few of the options like moderated email groups are not present.

I contacted Microsoft tech support about this and they said there was no way to override the settings in 365 because they were synced so i would have to add the extensions on my AD server

they suggested installing a trial of exchange then uninstalling it. That seems risky to me

Is there a save way to install the extensions

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you need to actually install Exchange to accomplish this. What they're referring to is extending the AD Schema for Exchange, which adds the Exchange related Schema data to AD. I don't necessarily see this as particularly risky. Here's a link to details on how to extend the Schema for Exchange Server 2013:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125224(v=exchg.150).aspx.

Note that you should only need to extend the Schema, you shouldn't need to prepare AD, but you should confirm that with Microsoft PSS.

Comment: the instructions seem a little fuzzy to me for step 1)-3) are they refering to download exhcnage trial  the run that command from the setup.exe from the excnage trial. I don't see anywhere that it refers to where to get the setup.exe

Comment: You need to download the installation package, unpack it and run `setup.exe` from there; there is no trial or full version, Exchange is always installed as a trial version until you enter a serial number. Here's the latest package: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43103.

Comment: @Crash893 if you can't figure out how to get to setup.exe from the install media, you may be beyond help.

Comment: Yea i got it. I just wasn't sure where to get the install media from

Answer (score 4):

What Microsoft said is right: the sync process is one-way, and some (well, a lot of) settings can not be managed by Office 365 in your scenario: they need to be configured on your local AD and then synced; however, your environment lacks any Exchange deployment, so those attributes don't even *exist* in your AD objects.

As joeqwerty said, extending the AD schema by running the relevant step in the Exchange setup (`setup.exe /PrepareSchema`) will take care of adding Exchange-related attributes to your AD, which will then be synced to Office 365.

However, since you don't have any local Exchange server, ***you'll have to manually edit those attributes using ADSIEdit or your favourite LDAP editor***, because there will be no Exchange tool to manage them.

Comment: where does one get the setup.exe from

Comment: You need to download the installation package, unpack it and run `setup.exe` from there; there is no trial or full version, Exchange is always installed as a trial version until you enter a serial number. Here's the latest package: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43103.

Comment: You can edit them through ADUC/ADAC as well.

Comment: @MDMarra any LDAP editor will do; but you still need to find the correct attribute and manually edit its value(s). Good luck adding an email alias if you don't know how ProxyAddresses work...

Comment: This is very true.

Comment: long term goal is to add distro group moderators

Comment: That would probably be even more awkward to do at the LDAP level than adding an email alias...